# How to add numbering to subsubsection in the table of content?

Tags: numbering, overleaf

I am working on my thesis and wanted to add another subheading with numbering. I am unable to do so. I have read online about it and people have mentioned that you can use \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} to increase the subheading levels. It didn't work for me. Can someone guide me on how I can include numbering in the subsubsection in the below latex template?

```
%%
%% This is file `fsuthesis.cls',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% fsuthesis.dtx  (with options: `class')
%% 
%% This is a generated file.
%% 
%% Copyright (c) 2010-2013 by Bret Whissel
%% 
%% This file may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
%% version 1.2 of this license or (at your option) any later
%% version.  The latest version of this license is in:
%% 
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% 
%% and version 1.2 or later is part of all distributions of
%% LaTeX version 1999/12/01 or later.
%% 
%for images we have used graphicx package and below line is to give path to all images.
\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{comment}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}
 
\usepackage{lipsum}
% \usepackage{sectsty}
% \sectionfont{\bfseries\Large\raggedright}

%----------Testing for subsection depth------------
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
%--------------------------------------------



\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2005/09/16]
\ProvidesClass{fsuthesis}
  [2015/05/05 v3.6.0
    (FSU LaTeX document class for Theses/Dissertations
     maintained by Bret Whissel, bwhissel@fsu.edu)]

\newif\if@hardcopy
\newif\if@expanded
\newif\ifch@pleaders
\newif\ifc@pyright
\DeclareOption{hardcopy}{\@hardcopytrue}
\DeclareOption{expanded}{\@expandedtrue}
\DeclareOption{chapterleaders}{\ch@pleaderstrue}
\DeclareOption{copyright}{\c@pyrighttrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ProcessOptions \relax
\LoadClass{report}
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\setlength{\headheight}{\topskip}
\setlength{\headsep}{10pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.35in}
\setlength{\@tempdima}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\@tempdima}{-2in}
\addtolength{\@tempdima}{-\footskip}
\divide\@tempdima\baselineskip
\@tempcnta=\@tempdima
\setlength\textheight{\@tempcnta\baselineskip}
\setlength{\footskip}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\footskip}{-2in}
\addtolength{\footskip}{-\textheight}
\setlength{\topmargin}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-\headheight}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-\headsep}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-\textheight}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-\footskip}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\@tempdima}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\@tempdima}{-2in}
\addtolength{\@tempdima}{-\textwidth}
\divide\@tempdima by2
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{\@tempdima}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\@tempdima}
\newlength{\evenoddoffset}
\setlength{\evenoddoffset}{0.25in}
\if@hardcopy%
  \AtBeginDocument{\addtolength{\textwidth}{-\evenoddoffset}%
    \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{\evenoddoffset}}
  \if@twoside\@openrighttrue%
    \AtBeginDocument{\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-\evenoddoffset}}
  \else
    \AtBeginDocument{\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{\evenoddoffset}}\fi
\fi
\ifch@pleaders
  \renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
    \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
      \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
      \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
      {\@dottedtocline{0}{0pt}{1.5em}{\bfseries#1}{\bfseries#2}}
    \fi}
\fi
\if@expanded
  \newlength{\adjbaselineskip}%
  \setlength{\adjbaselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}%
  \def\blstretchiness{0pt plus.4pt minus.3pt}
  \def\smblstretchiness{0pt plus.3pt minus.2pt}
  \let\FSU@onormalsize=\normalsize%
  \newcommand{\expandspacing}{\FSU@onormalsize%
     \addtolength{\baselineskip}{\adjbaselineskip}%
     \addtolength{\baselineskip}{\blstretchiness}}%
  \let\normalsize=\expandspacing%
  \newcommand{\afterheadadj}{\addvspace{-\adjbaselineskip}}%
  \let\f@olist=\list
  \def\list#1#2{%
    \f@olist{#1}{#2}
    \ifnum\@listdepth=1
      \setlength{\baselineskip}{2.4\adjbaselineskip}
      \addtolength{\baselineskip}{\smblstretchiness}
    \fi
  }
  \let\f@oendlist=\endlist
  \def\endlist{%
    \f@oendlist
    \ifnum\@listdepth=0 \normalsize \fi
  }
  \let\f@overbat=\verbatim
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\f@overbats
    \expandafter=\csname endverbatim*\endcsname
  \let\f@oendverb=\endverbatim
  \def\verbatim{\par\FSU@onormalsize\f@overbat}
  \def\endverbatim{\f@oendverb\afterheadadj}
  \@namedef{verbatim*}{\par\FSU@onormalsize\@verbatim\@sxverbatim}
  \expandafter\let\csname endverbatim*\endcsname =\endverbatim
\else
  \let\expandspacing=\relax
  \let\FSU@onormalsize=\relax
  \let\afterheadadj=\relax
  \let\f@olist=\list
  \let\f@oendlist=\endlist
\fi
\FSU@onormalsize
\newenvironment{singlespaced}
  {\par\if@expanded\FSU@onormalsize\addvspace{\adjbaselineskip}\fi}{\par}
\newif\if@hyperloaded
\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}
  {\@hyperloadedtrue}{\@hyperloadedfalse}}
\gdef\@degree{\ClassError{fsuthesis}%
  {No \protect\degree\space given}%
  {You must provide a \protect\degree{Degree Name}%
   \space command}}
\gdef\@department{\ClassError{fsuthesis}%
  {No \protect\department\space given}%
  {You must provide a \protect\department{Name of Department}%
   \space command}}
% \gdef\@college{\ClassError{fsuthesis}%
%   {No \protect\college\space given}%
%   {You must provide a \protect\college{My College or School}%
%   \space command}}
\gdef\@degreeyear{\ClassError{fsuthesis}%
  {No \protect\degreeyear\space given}%
  {You must provide a \protect\degreeyear{20NN}\space command}}
\gdef\@defensedate{\ClassError{fsuthesis}%
  {No \protect\defensedate\space given}%
  {You must provide a \protect\defensedate{Month dd, 20NN}%
   \space command}}
\gdef\@manuscripttype{\ClassError{fsuthesis}%
  {No \protect\manuscripttype\space given}%
  {You must provide a \protect\manuscripttype{Dissertation}%
   \space command}}
\newif\if@department
\newcommand*{\degree}[1]{\gdef\@degree{#1}}
\newcommand*{\department}[1]{\gdef\@department{#1}\@departmenttrue}
% \newcommand*{\college}[1]{\gdef\@college{#1}}
\newcommand*{\degreeyear}[1]{\gdef\@degreeyear{#1}}
\newcommand*{\defensedate}[1]{\gdef\@defensedate{#1}}
\newcommand*{\manuscripttype}[1]{\gdef\@manuscripttype{#1}}
\newcommand*{\semester}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\begin{titlepage}%
\ifpdf\if@hyperloaded\pdfbookmark[0]{Title Page}{MainTitlePage}\fi\fi
\enlargethispage{\footskip}%
\begin{center}%
\FSU@onormalsize
\vskip\baselineskip
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{UoH_logo.png}
% \MakeUppercase{\@college}%
\vfill
\vskip-\baselineskip
{\addtolength{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}%
\MakeUppercase{\@title}\vfill}
by
\vskip\baselineskip
\MakeUppercase{\@author}

\vfill
 \@manuscripttype{}\\
%  \@college{}\\
%  \@degreeyear
\vfill
\Medium
        School of Computing and Engineering\vskip 0.1in

% \vfill
% A \@manuscripttype{} submitted to the\\
% \if@department\@department\else\@college\fi\\
% \@degree
% \vfill
%\@degreeyear%
\vfill
%\ifc@pyright%
 % Copyright \copyright\ \@degreeyear\ \@author. All Rights Reserved.\fi%
\pagebreak[4]
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
}
\newlength{\commwidth}
\setlength{\commwidth}{3.75in}
\newlength{\commskip}
\setlength{\commskip}{0.5in plus0.25fil minus.3in}
\gdef\@thecmems{}
\newcommand{\committeeperson}[2]{%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\@thecmems\expandafter{%
    \@thecmems\vskip\commskip\makebox[\commwidth][l]{#1}\\
      \makebox[\commwidth][l]{#2}}}
\newcommand{\makecommitteepage}{\FSU@onormalsize\setcounter{page}{2}%
\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi%
{%\addtolength{\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}%
\setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox{\@author{} defended this
\MakeLowercase{\@manuscripttype} on \mbox{\@defensedate}.}
\ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\textwidth\raggedright\noindent\unhbox\@tempboxa{} \else
  \noindent\unhbox\@tempboxa\par\fi
\noindent The members of the supervisory committee were:\par}
\vfil\begin{flushright}\vskip-\commskip%
  \addtolength{\baselineskip}{0.4\baselineskip}\@thecmems\end{flushright}\vfil
\vskip\baselineskip
{%\addtolength{\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
\noindent
The Graduate School has verified and approved the
above-named committee members, and certifies that the
\MakeLowercase{\@manuscripttype} has been approved in accordance
with university requirements.\par}\vfil\pagebreak[4]}
\gdef\@subject{}
\gdef\@keywords{}
\newif\if@subject
\newif\if@keywords
\newcommand*{\subject}[1]{\gdef\@subject{#1}\@subjecttrue}
\newcommand*{\keywords}[1]{\gdef\@keywords{#1}\@keywordstrue}
\def\@pdfmetadata{{\def\protect{}\def\\{ }%
  \edef\@litstr{/Title (\@title) /Author (\@author)}%
  \if@subject\edef\@litstr{\@litstr /Subject (\@subject)}\fi%
  \if@keywords\edef\@litstr{\@litstr /Keywords (\@keywords)}\fi%
  \expandafter\pdfinfo\expandafter{\@litstr}}}
\def\@hypermetadata{{\def\\{ }\edef\@nt{\@title}%
  \hypersetup{pdftitle={\@nt},pdfauthor={\@author}}%
  \if@subject\hypersetup{pdfsubject={\@subject}}\fi%
  \if@keywords\hypersetup{pdfkeywords={\@keywords}}\fi}}
\AtBeginDocument{\ifpdf\if@hyperloaded\@hypermetadata\else\@pdfmetadata\fi\fi}
\newcommand{\frontmatter}{\pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand{\mainmatter}{%
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi%
  \expandspacing\pagenumbering{arabic}}
\newcommand*{\acknowledgename}{Acknowledgments}
\newcommand*{\biosketchname}{Biographical Sketch}
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\newcommand*{\listofpublicationsname}{List of Publications}
\newcommand*{\listmusexname}{List of Abbreviation}
\newcommand*{\listsymname}{List of Symbols}
\newcommand*{\musexname}{Example}
\newcommand*{\appendixtocname}{Appendix}
\newenvironment{dedication}%
  {\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi\mbox{}\vfill}
  {\vfill\vfill\vskip1in\mbox{}\pagebreak[4]}
\newenvironment{acknowledgments}%
  {\chapter*{\acknowledgename}\normalsize\afterheadadj}
  {\clearpage\FSU@onormalsize}
\newenvironment{listofsymbols}
  {\chapter*{\listsymname}\FSU@onormalsize%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{frontmatter}{\listsymname}}
  {\clearpage}
\newenvironment{listofpublications}
  {\chapter*{\listpublicationsname}\FSU@onormalsize%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{frontmatter}{\listpublicationsname}}
  {\clearpage}
\renewenvironment{abstract}%
  {\chapter*{\abstractname}\normalsize\afterheadadj%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{frontmatter}{\abstractname}}
  {\clearpage\FSU@onormalsize}
\newcount\listspenalty
\listspenalty=200
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty=\listspenalty
     \leavevmode \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}\par}%
  \fi}
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{
  \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn\else\@restonecolfalse\fi
  \chapter*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  \ifpdf\if@hyperloaded\pdfbookmark[0]{Table of Contents}{contents}\fi\fi
  {\listspenalty=10000\@starttoc{toc}\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi}%
}
\newif\iffront@dded
\newcommand*\l@frontmatter{%
  \iffront@dded\addvspace{1ex \@plus\p@}\else\front@ddedtrue\fi
  \@dottedtocline{0}{0pt}{0pt}}
\def\toclevel@frontmatter{1}
\newif\ifb@ckadded
\newcommand*\l@backmatter{%
  \ifb@ckadded\addpenalty{\@highpenalty}\addvspace{1ex \@plus\p@}%
    \addpenalty{\@highpenalty}%
  \else\b@ckaddedtrue\addpenalty{0}\addvspace{1em \@plus\p@}\fi%
  \@dottedtocline{0}{0pt}{0pt}}
\def\toclevel@backmatter{0}
\renewcommand*\l@figure{%
  \addvspace{10pt}%
  \@dottedtocline{0}{0pt}{3.2em}}
\let\l@table\l@figure
\newcommand{\FSU@lofsomething}[2]{\FSU@onormalsize%
  \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn\else\@restonecolfalse\fi
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \addvspace{-10pt}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{frontmatter}{#1}%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
  \@starttoc{#2}%
  \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
}
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{%
  \FSU@lofsomething{\listtablename}{lot}}
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{%
  \FSU@lofsomething{\listfigurename}{lof}}
  
\newcommand{\listofmusex}{%
  \FSU@lofsomething{\listmusexname}{lom}}
\let\l@musex\l@figure
\newcounter{musex}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\themusex}%
  {\ifnum\c@chapter>\z@\thechapter.\fi\@arabic\c@musex}
\newcommand{\theHmusex}%
  {\ifnum\c@chapter>\z@\thechapter.\fi\@arabic\c@musex}
\def\fps@musex{tbp}
\def\ftype@musex{1}
\def\ext@musex{lom}
\def\fnum@musex{\musexname\nobreakspace\themusex}
\newenvironment{musex}%
  {\@float{musex}}
  {\end@float}
\newenvironment{musex*}%
  {\@dblfloat{musex}}
  {\end@dblfloat}
\newskip{\refitemsep}
\newskip{\refindent}
{\FSU@onormalsize%
\global\setlength{\refitemsep}{\baselineskip}
\global\addtolength{\refitemsep}{0pt plus3pt minus0.2pt}}
\setlength{\refindent}{2.5em}
\newenvironment{references}
  {\chapter*{\bibname}\FSU@onormalsize%
   \interlinepenalty=10000\sloppy
   \addvspace{-\baselineskip} \@afterindenttrue%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{backmatter}{\bibname}%
   \setlength{\leftskip}{\refindent}%
   \setlength{\parindent}{-\refindent}%
   \setlength{\parskip}{\refitemsep}}
  {\clearpage}
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\chapter*{\bibname}\FSU@onormalsize%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{backmatter}{\bibname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      \f@olist{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
         {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
          \leftmargin\labelwidth
          \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
          \@openbib@code
          \usecounter{enumiv}%
          \let\p@enumiv\@empty
          \setlength{\itemsep}{\refitemsep}
          \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
          \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \interlinepenalty=10000
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \f@oendlist}
\def\f@plainnat{%
  \setlength{\bibsep}{\refitemsep}
  \setlength{\bibhang}{\refindent}
  \renewcommand\bibsection{\chapter*{\bibname}\FSU@onormalsize%
     \addcontentsline{toc}{backmatter}{\bibname}%
     \let\f@oldpre=\bibpreamble\let\f@oldpost=\bibpostamble%
     \renewcommand\bibpreamble{\f@oldpre\interlinepenalty=10000
       \if@expanded\let\f@savenlist=\list\let\list=\f@olist\fi}%
     \renewcommand\bibpostamble{%
       \if@expanded\let\list=\f@savenlist\fi\f@oldpost}}}
\def\f@apacite{%
  \renewcommand{\bibliographytypesize}{\FSU@onormalsize%
     \interlinepenalty=10000
     \if@expanded\let\f@savenlist=\list\let\list=\f@olist\fi}%
  \@ifpackageloaded{natbib}%
    {\renewcommand\bibsection{\chapter*{\bibname}
       \addcontentsline{toc}{backmatter}{\bibname}}
     \setlength{\bibsep}{\refitemsep}%
     \setlength{\bibhang}{\refindent}}%
    {\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\refitemsep}%
     \setlength{\bibleftmargin}{\refindent}%
     \setlength{\bibindent}{-\refindent}%
     \renewcommand{\st@rtbibchapter}{\chapter*{\bibname}%
         \addcontentsline{toc}{backmatter}{\bibname}}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{apacite}{\f@apacite}%
  {\@ifpackageloaded{natbib}{\f@plainnat}{}}}
\newenvironment{biosketch}
  {\chapter*{\biosketchname}\normalsize\afterheadadj%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{backmatter}{\biosketchname}}
  {\clearpage\FSU@onormalsize}
\newlength{\chapheadskip}
\sbox\@tempboxa{\LARGE\bfseries CHAPTER}
\setlength{\chapheadskip}{0in}
\addtolength{\chapheadskip}{-\ht\@tempboxa}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \hrule height0pt depth0pt width0pt\vskip\chapheadskip%
  {\centering\parindent=0pt\LARGE\bfseries%
   \ifnum\c@secnumdepth >\m@ne%
     \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}\space\thechapter\par
     \nobreak\vskip20pt\fi%
  \interlinepenalty\@M%
  \MakeUppercase{#1}\par\nobreak\addvspace{40pt}
  }
}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \hrule height0pt depth0pt width0pt\vskip\chapheadskip%
  {\raggedright\parindent=0pt\LARGE\bfseries%
  \interlinepenalty\@M%
  \MakeUppercase{#1}\par\nobreak\addvspace{40pt}
  }
}
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0pt}%
  {4.0ex plus1ex minus0.3ex}%
  {2.0ex plus0.3ex minus0.2ex}%
  {\normalfont\raggedright\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{0pt}%
  {3ex plus.8ex minus0.1ex}%
  {1.25ex plus0.1ex minus.1ex}%
  {\normalfont\raggedright\large\bfseries}}

\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{3}{0pt}%
  {3ex plus.8ex minus0.1ex}%
  {1.25ex plus0.1ex minus.1ex}%
  {\normalfont\raggedright\large\bfseries}}

\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]%
  {\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\parindent}%
    {1ex plus.5ex minus0.1ex}%
    {-0.75em}%
    {\normalfont\scshape}{#1.}}
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]%
  {\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
    {0pt}{-0.5em}{\normalfont\itshape}{#1.}}
\let\f@ldappendix=\appendix
\gdef\appendix{\f@ldappendix
  \if@hyperloaded\def\@currentHref{appendix.A}\fi
  \addcontentsline{toc}{appendix}{\appendixtocname}}
\newcommand*\l@appendix[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-2000}\vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \par
      \penalty\@highpenalty\vskip -0.35em\penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\def\toclevel@appendix{0}

\newlength{\fcapindent}
\setlength{\fcapindent}{2em}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{10\p@}
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip%
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    {\advance\leftskip\fcapindent \rightskip=\leftskip\relax%
     \FSU@onormalsize%
     #1: #2\par}
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `fsuthesis.cls'.
```

Comment: The shown class file is broken. For example, it loads package `enumitem` before the font sizes have been defined, which results in an undefined control sequence error. And because [there is a newer version of the class](https://myweb.fsu.edu/bwhissel/fsulatex) without such mistakes, I would suggest to try the up-to-date version and to not modify it. If you need additional packages, load it in your document preamble. If you need modification, do them in your document preamble. If you then still have problems, show a minimal working example.

Comment: Since the maintainer also offers help, you perhaps could contact them directly?  https://myweb.fsu.edu/bwhissel/fsulatex/help.html